# 'a way that no one could have predicted'

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clauses, noun-phrases, content-clauses

Is "that no one could have predicted" a relative clause modifying the noun "way"?

**Events unfolded in a way that no one could have predicted**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Events unfolded in a way that no one could have predicted.
> 2. He had an idea that the money had disappeared.

Sometimes it is difficult to know whether a *that*-clause is a normal content clause (a normal finite subordinate clause), or a relative clause. If we think the clause is attached to a noun like *way* or *idea* there is a little test we can do. We can try to replace the word *that* with the word *which*. If the result is grammatical, then this is a relative clause. If it's ungrammatical, then the clause is probably a normal [declarative content] clause.

If we do this with the original poster's example we get:

> 3. Events unfolded in a way which no one could have predicted.

This is maybe less elegant than the original, but is perfectly grammatical. This means that the clause was a relative clause.

Let's try this with example (2):

> 4. *He had an idea which the money had disappeared. (ungrammatical)

Because this isn't grammatical, we know that *that the money had disappeared* in (2) is a content clause, not a relative clause.

---

**<sup>Grammar note:</sup>**

<sup>This test will not work with a small number of nouns such as *day, time* and *place*. this is because these nouns can take special types of relative clauses which use *when* or *where* instead of *which*.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer.